# How to use the Rich Text Publisher plugin in a pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to display HTML reports in my pipeline.
For that, I intended to reuse the Rich Text Publisher plugin which I had used in the past, for "normal" jobs or matrix jobs, but I can't succeed in doing that :)

Here is my current pipeline:

```
pipeline{
    agent { label 'master' }
    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
    stages {
        stage('Workspace initialization'){
            steps{
                deleteDir()
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
        stage('main stage') {
            matrix {
                agent any
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'PRODUCT'
                        values 'product_A', 'product_B'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Quality') {
                        steps {
                            catchError(buildResult:'UNSTABLE', stageResult:'FAILURE') {
                                echo "Quality analysis for ${PRODUCT}"
                                sh 'mkdir -p artifacts/${PRODUCT}; echo "<h2>HTML report for ${PRODUCT}</h2>" > artifacts/${PRODUCT}/summary.html'
                            }
                            rtp {
                                stableText """<html><head><title>Report</title></head> <body>plop</body></html>"""
                                unstableAsStable true
                                failedAsStable true
                                parserName 'HTML'
                                abortedAsStable true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'artifacts/**/*'
        }
    }
}
```

The pipeline fails with the following error:

```
Also:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@926e420
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@4251545f
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.singleParam(DSL.java:718)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:706)
...
```

So my question is: how to use the Rich text publisher plugin in a pipeline context?

And a bonus one, more general, how to infer this information from a plugin's documentation (for example, [the rich text publisher plugin documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/rich-text-publisher-plugin/)).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation and the error message, the `rtp` method expects named arguments. According to the code and your error message, you are passing a single argument of type `Closure[String]` instead. You can conform to the proper usage by converting the argument to named arguments like the following:

```
rtp(
  stableText:       '<html><head><title>Report</title></head> <body>plop</body></html>'
  unstableAsStable: true
  failedAsStable:   true
  parserName:       'HTML'
  abortedAsStable:  true
)
```

and that will fix your error.

Comment: Thank you very much! I could progress one step further.
Now I've changed the rtp part with something like:
```rtp stableText: '<html><head><title>Report</title></head> <body>plop</body></html>', parserName: 'HTML'```
and it works, at least, the pipeline isn't failing anymore.
But the plugin publishes nothing and says in the logs:
```RTP: Ignoring buildresult==null aka publishing nothing!```
Any idea?

Comment: @ncarrier You can certainly ask a new question about that new issue, and see what answers are provided.

Comment: Ok, I think I've answered my own (second) question, it seems that the rtp plugin needs the status to be set before executing, so when put in a post section, it works fine.
I won't have per product pages, but I'm showing a global report gathering all the products' reports, so to me, the problem is fully solved. Thanks again :)